# How to set nested view and controller using ui.router using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular `ui.router` or routing my view. But here I need to set nested view and controller using Angular.js . I am providing my code below.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js" ng-app="ikomplianzNABH">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>ikomplianz</title>
<script src="../jsLib/js/angularjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jsLib/js/angularuirouter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="View/js/NABHRoute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="View/js/NABHController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top" onLoad="goforit()">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div  ui-view></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

route.js:

```
var compliance=angular.module('ikomplianzNABH',['ui.router']);
compliance.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
compliance.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('/', { /*....This state defines All type of user login...*/
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'View/NABH.html',
        controller: 'NABHController'
    })
});
```

Here When initially URL is running `NABH.html` is appending inside the `index.html's` `<div  ui-view></div>` part. The `NABH.html` is given below.

NABH.html:

```
<div  id="nabhinitiate">
 //here need to another html part and add new controller or it.


</div>

<div class="clecklist">
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Here I need when user will click on `Click Me` button the below `HTML` page will set inside this `<div  id="nabhinitiate"></div>` of `NABH.html` and `<div class="clecklist"><button type="button">Click Me</button></div>` will be hide.

nabhinitiate.html:

```
<h1>Hello child page </h1>
```

Here I need a child controller for this view also and in the same URL I need to routing it. [**Here is the plunkr code**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eR5uxSs5rQqSdTtiH7Pl?p=preview).

Comment: I would suggest you use a custom directive for your NABH

Comment: Can you help me to do this ?

Comment: Can you put this code in Fiddle or Codepen or Plunker?

Comment: @VicJordan : Ok,I am doing one plunkr.

Comment: @VicJordan : Here is my [plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/eR5uxSs5rQqSdTtiH7Pl?p=preview). Here I need to route both part from one html page with different controller.

Comment: Go through this link you will get an answer  :  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views